# Thin plate spline on Linear Network with Spatstat

Tags: r, spatstat

I have been using `lppm` from *spatstat* and I want to fit a log-linear model.
I can define covariates as `linfun` object and use in the model.
Let's say we are interested in modeling the car theft problem in Australia. let's assume `cov1` is the distance to the nearest school and `cov2` is the distance to the nearest police department.

We want to use `X` and `Y` coordinates in the model.

`lppm(L~cov1+cov2+x+y}` would work? X and Y's in the model are the location of events?

how can I use **thin-plate spline** on the linear network? I can create grids on `ppp` but `lpp` is not as straight forward as I think. Can I pass a matrix to `lppm` object?

Answer (score 0):

Code in `spatstat` for linear networks is still under development, but `lppm` is based upon `ppm`, so you can look at the help files or documents about `ppm` for explanation. The *variable names* appearing in the model formula can be

- the names of images (of class `im` or `linim`)
- the names of spatial functions (class `funxy` or `linfun`)
- the symbols `x`, `y` (representing cartesian coordinates)
- the symbol `marks` representing categorical mark value

A *term* in the model formula may be just the name of one of these variables, or an expression involving these variable names, including functions applied to these variables.

Your example would work.

You can get B-splines of the cartesian coordinates by including a term such as `bs(x)`

If you need more help, first read chapter 9 of [the spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org)

Comment: Hi @iHermes. This comment is hard to read/understand. Please edit your question to contain reproducible code of what you have done so far and what the remaining problem is.

Comment: @EgeRubak I actually make it working and get an error for tps because the values computed from tps is not small so it causes fisher matrix to the singular. I am working on how to eliminate that problem. rescale would be an option in that case, how to reschale estimates back?